# Использование пропускной способности по месяцам

Tags: администрирование

Сегодня мне письмо прислали от хостера, такая проблема: использование пропускной способности по месяцам заполнена. Там доступно 2000 Mb, 1924.41 Mb заполнена.

Как это можно исправить, и как это будет влиять на работу сайта?

Answer (score 4):

Все просто. Вам предоставляется 2000МБ трафика в месяц. Как только трафик превысит это значение сайт отключится. Вы этот лимит практически исчерпали. Возможно в этом месяце был наплыв посетителей на сайт, а возможно Вы занимались его тех.обслуживанием и гоняли файлы туда-сюда. Это не столь важно. Важно то, что это подтверждается тем, что лимит был достигнут только сейчас, т.е. во второй половине месяца. Решение простое - докупить пропускной способности у хостера. Если на сайт реально возросла в последнее (см. статистику, возможно в панели администратора сайта) - перейти на более "продвинутый" тарифный план.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо Вам.

Comment: Если ответ нравится, то можете проголосовать за него или принять.